# Why my PhD supervisors do not want to be involved in my research ideas?

Tags: publications, phd, advisor

I am a PhD student close to finishing my 1st year, highly motivated, passionate, hard working and with one accepted article in a really good journal (related to PhD project) plus conference proceedings.

I would like to grow as a scientist and also develop my ideas and therefore having a good research portfolio (i.e. papers) is essential for an early career scientist as me.

I am trying to share some of my research ideas, which are something extra outside the PhD project (multi-task), with my PhD supervisors but it seems that they won't listen or are not interested.

Why are the not involving/listening to me in their ongoing research?

My field is applied physical sciences and I am based in 'EU'.

Comment: Where are you located? In the US? Abroad? Are your ideas related to the work being done in the group? There's not really enough information here to give you a reliable answer.

Comment: You said you shared your ideas with your advisers, but have you asked about their ideas and expressed an interest in being involved in any of their upcoming or ongoing projects? If it's just been a one-way conversation so far, asking questions about their plans, interests, current and planned projects can be a very effective way to get a conversation started - and then, of course, listen thoughtfully and carefully. You can then decide if there is something you want to be involved with, express your interest, and/or ask to be a part.

Comment: What makes you think they "won't listen or are not interested"? Could it be that they don't have the time/money to test your ideas?

Comment: The title is misleading. It's not that they're not involving you in *their* research. It's that they're not getting involved in *your* research.

Comment: Without knowing the situation and the people concerned, we can't really know why they're not interested in your ideas. However, a PhD is essentially a full-time job and your advisors would probably prefer that you concentrate on your PhD rather than filling your time with side projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is time to have a meta-discussion about this.
You are a first year PhD student. At that time it is important for you to get your own main project(s) going and come up with ideas to improve that. Already repeatedly talking about side-projects that as you say are not very related to your PhD project is not necessarily a good idea.

While your ideas might be interesting, there are other points to consider. They might not fit your supervisor's research portfolio. Which means that it is not worth for them to spend their or your time on. They might not be feasible to be pursued for your group because of a lack of infrastructure (in applied physical sciences I would expect infrastructure to be very important).

Try talking about the general fact that you want to take up on a side project and develop the basis of that project together with your supervisor. Involve them in your plans, so they will start to involve you in theirs. Or come up with an idea that actually relates to one of their other projects and might be interesting for both of you.

Otherwise, keep the ideas. Revisit them later on, maybe one of them will be the basis of your first PostDoc grant.

Comment: It's not clear whether the OP is a theorist or an experimentalist. I would guess theorist, which means that the lack of infrastructure is irrelevant. (And yes, there are theorists in the applied physical sciences.)

Answer (score 4):

Who suggested your PhD project?

Ask your advisors to suggest some research problems for you.

There are a few graduate students who don't seem to want to have research projects suggested to them, but seem to want to work more or less independently. And if they succeed in publishing lots of good papers this way, there may be no real reason for their advisors to direct their research — they're already scientifically mature enough to manage their own research programs. Your advisor may think you are one of these rare graduate students who prefers to work on your own.

If you suggest research directions to your advisors, these directions may not fit in with their own research programs, and they are also likely to be very busy, and not have time to collaborate with you. So your advisors might not get involved with your research ideas. (Or they easily may, depending.) If you ask your advisors for a few suggested problems, they are much more likely to be interested in collaborating.

Comment: Isn't the point of a research _advisor_ to advice a young (1st year) PhD student on the potential of her/his research ideas? Usually, 1st years are not very mature enough to pursue their research. I agree with your answer that maybe the advisor thinks that the student is stellar and does not need guidance, but at least this should come in an encouraging way, not just by ignoring the student (that is the feeling I got)

Comment: @PsySp: While that may be the ***ideal*** relationship between a student and a research advisor, it isn't always what happens in real life. If the student came up with their own research direction that the advisor doesn't have much feel for, it will take quite a bit of time to understand it and offer constructive suggestions. And the advisor may have some other students who are really struggling. I'm trying to give some constructive advice, rather than just saying "your advisor sucks" (which is the message I would take away from your comment).

Comment: @PsySp: First-year students are generally not mature enough to get several conference proceedings and a paper in a really good journal while being ignored by their advisor. Usually, an advisor suggests a problem for the student to work on, and not the other way around (which it seems the OP wants to do). The advisor may think he's being encouraging, while the student may not perceive it that way.

Comment: Agree. We do not have much info, we are just guessing the advisor's motivation on not involving the student in his research assuming good faith (of course!) In any event, there is an obvious problem in the established communication which could pile up to a more serious problem in the future (the student should defend at some point, to the advisor as well). Even if the advisor thinks he is encouraging the student, then this obviously is not working. (btw I did not imply that the "advisor sucks" rather than the communication "sucks"). Thus, I agree with the advise to go and ask directly.

Comment: The ideas I am proposing are something extra outside the PhD project -> multi-task.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to ask them about their current projects/ideas but I don't want to appear the one who bothers people for just a name on a paper, i.e. I don't like begging and eventually become 'noted' only because I am the student of X. You know what? no one cares about my ideas..I will try to develop them on my own without ignoring my PhD project. Thank you

Comment: One of your advisor's roles is to give you ideas for projects to work on. I hope they wouldn't think you were bothering them just to get a name on a paper.